# Gdal creating raster rotated wrong way

Tags: python, raster, gdal, imagery

I have been trying to read in a stack of images for a timeseries and created an output raster that contains the max pixel values of the timeseries.

The arrays were created using numpy

```
img_stack = np.empty((image_width, image_length, len(image_files)), np.dtype('f'))      
final_values = np.empty((image_length, image_width), np.dtype('f'))
```

I imported the image using the following loop:

```
for i, fname in enumerate(image_files):
    img = gdal.Open(os.path.join(fn + ("\{0}".format(fname)))).ReadAsArray()
    img_stack[:, :, i] = img
```

then I read the values into a 2D list using the following nested loop:

```
for x in range(image_length):
    for y in range(image_width):
        final_values[x][y] = 0
        for z in range(len(image_files)):
            if (final_values[x][y] < img_stack[y, 0, z]):
                final_values[x][y] = (img_stack[y, 0, z])
            else:
                next
```

then use

```
output_raster = dr.Create(final, image_width, image_length, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
output_raster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(final_values)
```

the output contains the correct pixel values, but is rotated 90 degrees to the left.

I believe the issue is due to GDAL reading the image as an array first by width and then by length, but I am not sure.

Is there an issues with my code or is there a function I could use to rotate it to the proper orientation?

Thanks

Comment: Is the output truly rotated or has it actually been *reflected*?  A reflection would result from transposing the row and column coordinates whereas a rotation would suggest the row and column coordinates have been transposed *and* the order of the rows has been reversed.  (These are the two details that cause the most problems when converting among various raster and array indexing conventions.)

Comment: the output is neither reflected nor rotated, it's gibberish. As noted in Marc Pfister's reply, the code is checking img_stack[y, 0, z], but setting final_values[x,y]. The x var indexes image_length, which makes the code somewhat inscrutable to the casual reader, but also means that for a non-square array, img_stack should be getting array bound errors if width > length. In addition, only the first (0) column values are read, but written into the max for every column (though transposed in the process)

Comment: another thing - this approach will eat memory like crazy if the images are large and there are many images. It would be more space efficient to read one image and compare its pixel values to the current high value, then read the next image, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're accessing

```
img_stack[y, 0, z]
```

instead of

```
img_stack[x, y, z]
```

But let's make it easier - if you want the maximum values in a numpy array along your z axis, you should be able to use:

```
final_values = numpy.amax(img_stack, axis=2)
```

see [numpy.amax](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html)